# How can we Increase the Task Managers in Apache Flink application

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, taskmanager, amazon-kinesis-analytics

In AWS kinesis data analytics application , integrated the Apache flink application. In apache flink dashboard Task Managers count is 2 but need to add 2 more Task Managers in apache flink for improving performance.

How can we add Task Managers in Apache flink application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase parallelism of the job and/or decrease slots number.
Ex:

- parallelism 4 2 slots => Flink will allocate 2 TM
- parallelism 4 1 slot  => Flink will allocate 4 TM

You can read more about it [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/concepts/flink-architecture/#taskmanagers)

Comment: These things are probably not present on kinesis.
Kinesis has Parallelism and parallelism per KPU. Which then converts in to KPU.
Is there a way to allocate task managers using these units in Amazon Kinesis.?